# Flutter dropdownbutton evaluting value from json

Tags: json, flutter, dropdownbutton

````
```{"Piece": "[{\"sno\":7,\"valueName\":\"3\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"sno\":7,\"valueName\":\"3\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"sno\":7,\"valueName\":\"3\",\"value\":\"200\"}]",
"Caret": "[{\"sno\":1,\"valueName\":\"18k\",\"value\":\"1000\"},{\"sno\":1,\"valueName\":\"18k\",\"value\":\"1000\"},{\"sno\":1,\"valueName\":\"18k\",\"value\":\"1000\"},{\"sno\":1,\"valueName\":\"18k\",\"value\":\"1000\"}]"
````

}```

I have a json response from server like above. and I want to create dropdownbuttons dynamically in a way that how many keys are available like 'Caret' and 'piece' in json, it will create the same no of dropdown and each key has its own list and I want to deploy that list inside the drop down. and when I select any valueName like '18k','22k', it will return value like '1000','2000'.
please help me.

I tried...

````
Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: data2.keys.length,
                        primary: false,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          List valueList;
                          List attributeNameList= List();
                          data2.forEach((key, value) {attributeNameList.add(key);valueList=jsonDecode(value);});
                          return DropdownButton<dynamic>(
                            items: valueList.map((map) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                child: Text(map['valueName']),
                                value: map['value'],
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              print(value);
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),```
````

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: but I get very weird result in drop down.
mixing of 2 lists

Comment: What `data2` holds? is it that json?

Comment: yes data2 is a Map<String, dynamic> which is holding above JSON Data

Comment: If it is a map thats means you havde decoded it earlier, so you dont need to decode again in this line `List ab=jsonDecode(map);`.

Comment: Did you get any errors or whats the output of your try?

Comment: @Blasanka every thing is working good.
I have updated the 'I Tried' the code. every thing is working good.
but all dropdown have same value and text.
data2.forEach((key, value) {attributeNameList.add(key);valueList=jsonDecode(value);});
because of this.
I am not getting how to get one value at a time.

Comment: and there is one more problem with setselectedvalue.
as I am using different text and different value in drop down so it is giving me error for that to use same text value. but when using onChange method it is returning me value!
so how to set that user can see what he is actually selected!

Comment: You are getting the same value because you are doing it in the listview builder. So each and every time for list item you are replacing list values. Instead what you should do is make those list class fields and forEach in initState or somewhere but not inside listview. Becasue looking at your code, iterating inside listview is point less.

Comment: so how will I create dynamic drop down! with dynamic name and its value!
tomorrow is Sunday.
if u r free at any time then can u please come to any desk or team viewer and help me with this.
it is a request please......
I have mailed you with Tushark*** email id to your yahoo mail.
if u r free then please help me. and please revert to that mail. I am waiting for your reply eagrly